# How to batch import Wavefront OBJ files?

Tags: objects, import, obj

Is it possible to batch import Wavefront *.obj* to blender? I'm working on 2.69.
If I select multiple *.obj* files, only one gets imported. Also if I hit A on file selection window to select all files (*.obj* and *.mtl*) I get an error, nothing gets imported. I have to import several hundreds of *.obj* into the blender file, is this possible?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible by default with Blender 2.5x+ it seems. In 2.49, you could hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> then press the *Import Obj* button and it would prompt you to select a directory with the sequence.

In 2.69 - and at least until 2.82 - you can do the same with a script — *it could be converted into a more usable utility but it works.*

```
import os
import bpy

# put the location to the folder where the objs are located here in this fashion
# this line will only work on windows ie C:\objects
path_to_obj_dir = os.path.join('C:\\', 'objects')
 
# get list of all files in directory
file_list = sorted(os.listdir(path_to_obj_dir))
 
# get a list of files ending in 'obj'
obj_list = [item for item in file_list if item.endswith('.obj')]
 
# loop through the strings in obj_list and add the files to the scene
for item in obj_list:
    path_to_file = os.path.join(path_to_obj_dir, item)
    bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath = path_to_file, use_split_objects=False, use_split_groups=False)
```

For unix machines the direct path should look like:

```
# location of obj folder
path_to_obj_dir = '/home/user/Desktop/objects/'
```

Comment: To use the script, simply paste it into Blender's text editor, edit the path on the 5th line and press `Alt + P` or _Run_.

Comment: Thank you so much, works like a charm, but I had to do some research and trial error with my very poor knowledge of python. I had to change the extension to OBJ because by using print(obj_list) I noticed that it wasn't seeing the objs that had an uppercase extension, checked it with print(file_list) and then changed to OBJ and it worked!

Comment: @akzash rejected your suggested edit re removing objects from windwos path. Your error would be in that you don't have an objects folder in c drive.

Comment: @iKlsR I am importing many `.obj` files sequentially. Very quickly, import time increases significantly to the point that it takes minutes for each object to get imported. Could you please take a look at my question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102333/importing-new-obj-files-becomes-extremely-slow-even-when-old-objects-are-remove) and see if you can offer a solution?  Appreciate it.

Comment: FWIW the same `bpy.ops.import_scene.obj()` method will also work in Blender 2.82.

Answer (score 36):

The following Add-on allows to **import multiple Wavefront OBJ files** at once. By using the file browser the import process is *platform independent*. Also all the usual options like *Forward Axis*, *Up Axis* or *Clamp Size* are available.

**Repository**: [github.com/p2or/blender-batch-import-wavefront-obj](https://github.com/p2or/blender-batch-import-wavefront-obj)

[image]

#### [`io_batch_import_objs.py`](https://github.com/p2or/blender-batch-import-wavefront-obj/releases/download/v0.7.0/io_batch_import_objs.py) (updated for 3.5+)

```
# ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#  Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
# ##### END GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
# <pep8 compliant>


bl_info = {
    "name": "Batch Import Wavefront (.obj)",
    "author": "p2or",
    "version": (0, 7, 0),
    "blender": (3, 5, 0),
    "location": "File > Import-Export",
    "description": "Import multiple OBJ files, UV's and their materials",
    "doc_url": "https://github.com/p2or/blender-batch-import-wavefront-obj",
    "tracker_url": "https://github.com/p2or/blender-batch-import-wavefront-obj",
    "category": "Import-Export"}


import bpy
from pathlib import Path

from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper

from bpy.props import (BoolProperty,
                       FloatProperty,
                       StringProperty,
                       EnumProperty,
                       CollectionProperty)


class WM_OT_batchWavefront(bpy.types.Operator, ImportHelper):
    """Batch Import Wavefront"""
    bl_idname = "wm.obj_import_batch"
    bl_label = "Import multiple OBJ's"
    bl_options = {'PRESET', 'UNDO'}

    filename_ext = ".obj"

    filter_glob = StringProperty(
            default="*.obj",
            options={'HIDDEN'})

    files: CollectionProperty(type=bpy.types.PropertyGroup)
    
    global_scale_setting: FloatProperty(
            name="Scale",
            description="Value by which to enlarge or shrink" \
                    "the objects with respect to the world origin",
            min=0.0001, max=10000.0,
            soft_min=0.01, soft_max=1000.0,
            default=1.0)

    clamp_size_setting: FloatProperty(
            name="Clamp Bounding Box",
            description="Resize the objects to keep bounding box" \
                    "under this value. Value 0 diables clamping",
            min=0.0, max=1000.0,
            soft_min=0.0, soft_max=1000.0,
            default=0.0)
    
    axis_forward_setting: EnumProperty(
            name="Forward Axis",
            items=(('X', "X", ""),
                   ('Y', "Y", ""),
                   ('Z', "Z", ""),
                   ('NEGATIVE_X', "-X", ""),
                   ('NEGATIVE_Y', "-Y", ""),
                   ('NEGATIVE_Z', "-Z", ""),
                   ),
            default='NEGATIVE_Z')
            
    axis_up_setting: EnumProperty(
            name="Up Axis",
            items=(('X', "X", ""),
                   ('Y', "Y", ""),
                   ('Z', "Z", ""),
                   ('NEGATIVE_X', "-X", ""),
                   ('NEGATIVE_Y', "-Y", ""),
                   ('NEGATIVE_Z', "-Z", ""),
                   ),
            default='Y')
            
    validate_setting: BoolProperty(
            name="Validate Meshes",
            description="Check imported mesh objects for invalid data")
    
    vgroup_setting: BoolProperty(
            name="Vertex Groups",
            description="Import OBJ groups as vertex groups")

    use_split_objects_setting: BoolProperty(
            name="Split By Object",
            default=True,
            description="Import each OBJ 'o' as a separate object")

    use_split_groups_setting: BoolProperty(
            name="Split By Group",
            description="Import each OBJ 'o' as a separate object")
            
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = False  # No animation.
        
        box = layout.box()
        box.label(text="Transform", icon='OBJECT_DATA')
        col = box.column()
        col.prop(self, "global_scale_setting")
        col.prop(self, "clamp_size_setting")
        col.separator()
        col.row().prop(self, "axis_forward_setting", expand=True)
        col.separator(factor=0.5)
        col.row().prop(self, "axis_up_setting", expand=True)
        col.separator()
        
        box = layout.box()
        box.label(text="Options", icon='EXPORT')
        col = box.column()
        col.prop(self, "use_split_objects_setting")
        col.prop(self, "use_split_groups_setting")
        col.prop(self, "vgroup_setting")
        col.prop(self, "validate_setting")

    def execute(self, context):
        folder = Path(self.filepath)
        for selection in self.files:
            fp = Path(folder.parent, selection.name)
            if fp.suffix == '.obj':
                bpy.ops.wm.obj_import(
                                filepath = str(fp),
                                global_scale = self.global_scale_setting,
                                clamp_size = self.clamp_size_setting,
                                forward_axis = self.axis_forward_setting,
                                up_axis = self.axis_up_setting,
                                use_split_objects = self.use_split_objects_setting,
                                use_split_groups = self.use_split_groups_setting,
                                import_vertex_groups = self.vgroup_setting,
                                validate_meshes = self.validate_setting
                                )
        return {'FINISHED'}


def menu_func_import(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(
                WM_OT_batchWavefront.bl_idname, 
                text="Wavefront Batch (.obj)")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(WM_OT_batchWavefront)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_import.append(menu_func_import)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WM_OT_batchWavefront)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_import.remove(menu_func_import)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    #bpy.ops.wm.obj_import_batch('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

**Note:** It is basically just a quick and dirty wrapper of [`wm.obj_import`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html?highlight=obj_import#bpy.ops.wm.obj_import) or [`import_scene.obj`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_5/bpy.ops.import_scene.html?highlight=import_scene.obj#bpy.ops.import_scene.obj) operator in versions prior to Blender `3.2.0` until *batch import* is supported. To batch export scene objects, see: [Export multiple objects to .obj?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31852/3710)

#### Versions

To keep track of all the changes over the years I decided to create a [dedicated repository](https://github.com/p2or/blender-batch-import-wavefront-obj) instead of posting each version here, which makes it easier to download as well:

| Blender | Addon Version | Release |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Blender 2.65+ | 0.1.0 | [Download](https://github.com/p2or/blender-batch-import-wavefront-obj/releases/download/v0.1.0/io_batch_import_objs.py) |
| Blender 2.80+ | 0.2.0 | [Download](https://github.com/p2or/blender-batch-import-wavefront-obj/releases/download/v0.2.0/io_batch_import_objs.py) |
| Blender 2.92+ | 0.3.0 | [Download](https://github.com/p2or/blender-batch-import-wavefront-obj/releases/download/v0.3.0/io_batch_import_objs.py) |
| Blender 3.2+ | 0.4.0 | [Download](https://github.com/p2or/blender-batch-import-wavefront-obj/releases/download/v0.4.0/io_batch_import_objs.py) |
| Blender 3.3+ | 0.5.0 | [Download](https://github.com/p2or/blender-batch-import-wavefront-obj/releases/download/v0.5.0/io_batch_import_objs.py) |
| Blender 3.4+ | 0.6.1 | [Download](https://github.com/p2or/blender-batch-import-wavefront-obj/releases/download/v0.6.1/io_batch_import_objs.py) |
| Blender 3.5+ | 0.7.0 | [Download](https://github.com/p2or/blender-batch-import-wavefront-obj/releases/download/v0.7.0/io_batch_import_objs.py) |

[@JuhaW](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/7474) added a *Scale setting* to `0.2.0`, you can download the latest version [from here](https://gist.github.com/p2or/af5bc4fae39b16f8d505).

---

Comment: Just wanted to add, THANKS. This helped my workflow immeasurably. I'm consolidating torus knots (KnotPlot) of MULTIPLE
obj components and was looking for a way to streamline
this import process. Your process (addon) reduced it to seconds. THANKS.

Comment: Many thanks poor, works with Blender 2.76.11.

Comment: @JuhaW For collaborative work I thought it's a good idea to create a gist, instead of updating the answer continuously. I hope you like it. Thanks again.

Comment: How did you manage to offset the loaded OBJs? I can't see it in the example code. I could need it for importing an OBJ to a custom position and parent it.

Comment: @RayKoopa There is none, it's just an example for demo purposes. For parenting, read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28762/3710 But why not simply asking a new question on this?

Comment: @poor I originally wondered how you'd access an object created by an operator. I solved it by just giving them unique names in the operator of the other add-on to find them when being back in my add-on.

Comment: You can access the respective imported object with `context.selected_objects[0]`. For demonstration purposes I added a *parent property* to the interface: https://gist.github.com/p2or/d4956ed05af4618fab0b7f931c50f990. If it's enabled it will create an empty as parent for all imported objects automatically. I hope this is what you want @RayKoopa, right?

Comment: But that requires those objects were selected by the operator, my operator in the other add-on doesn't do that at the moment =3

Comment: @RayKoopa This happens automatically, after calling the operator. Please test and read my example carefully. Do a `print(obj_list)` after `bpy.ops.import_scene.obj` in the Add-on and you'll see that this will work

Comment: Yes, but I'm using my own import operator in my own add-on which I want to call in from another add-on I write; and my add-on doesn't select it. The OBJ one does. Anyway, I could solve my problem.

Comment: sweet, 2.92+ works on 3.0.1, which is awesome