# Export multiple objects to .obj

Tags: export, file-format, obj

It is possible to export all object from a scene into different obj files (each object in a obj file separately)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There doesn't exist a way to do this in the options of the obj importer so what you could do is run a script that loops over the items in your scene,
check if it is a mesh and export the current selection to its own file relative to the path your blend file is saved.

**Blender 3.1+**

As of Blender 3.1.0 the name of the operator has been changed to [`obj_export()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/dev/bpy.ops.wm.html?highlight=obj_export#bpy.ops.wm.obj_export) and is now part of the [`WindowManager`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html?highlight=windowmanager#bpy.types.WindowManager) namespace [`bpy.ops.wm.obj_export(filepath="//")`](https://docs.blender.org/api/dev/bpy.ops.wm.html?highlight=obj_export#bpy.ops.wm.obj_export):

```
import bpy
import os

# Get the path where the blend file is located
basedir = bpy.path.abspath('//')

# Deselect all objects
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')    

# loop through all the objects in the scene
scene = bpy.context.scene
for ob in scene.objects:
    # Select each object
    ob.select_set(True)

    # Make sure that we only export meshes
    if ob.type == 'MESH':
        # Export the currently selected object to its own file based on its name
        bpy.ops.wm.obj_export(
            filepath=os.path.join(basedir, ob.name + '.obj'),
            export_selected_objects=True,
            )
    # Deselect the object and move on to another if any more are left
    ob.select_set(False)
```

**Blender 2.8+**

As of [Blender 2.8.0](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Scene_and_Object_API#Object_Selection_and_Hiding) the selection attribute ([`Object.select`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=select#bpy.types.Object.select)) has been removed in favor of get/set functions [`Object.select_set(State)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=select_set#bpy.types.Object.select_set) and [`Object.select_get()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.select_get) to set and get the current selection state of each object:

```
import bpy
import os

# Get the path where the blend file is located
basedir = bpy.path.abspath('//')

# Deselect all objects
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')    

# loop through all the objects in the scene
scene = bpy.context.scene
for ob in scene.objects:
    # Select each object
    ob.select_set(True)

    # Make sure that we only export meshes
    if ob.type == 'MESH':
        # Export the currently selected object to its own file based on its name
        bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(
                filepath=os.path.join(basedir, ob.name + '.obj'),
                use_selection=True,
                )
    # Deselect the object and move on to another if any more are left
    ob.select_set(False)
```

**Blender 2.7x**

```
import bpy
import os

# Get the path where the blend file is located
basedir = bpy.path.abspath('//')

# Deselect all objects
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')    

# Loop through all the objects in the scene
scene = bpy.context.scene
for ob in scene.objects:
    # Make the current object active and select it
    scene.objects.active = ob
    ob.select = True
    
    # Make sure that we only export meshes
    if ob.type == 'MESH':
        # Export the currently selected object to its own file based on its name
        bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(
                filepath=os.path.join(basedir, ob.name + '.obj'),
                use_selection=True,
                )
    # Deselect the object and move on to another if any more are left
    ob.select = False
```

To further tweak your export options, see the parameters that
[`bpy.ops.export_scene_obj()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.export_scene.html#bpy.ops.export_scene.obj) accepts.
For example, you can include normals with `use_normals=True`, change forward axis with `axis_forward` etc.

There are more stringent checks that could be made but for simple use cases and if used properly, this should suffice.

Also see [How to batch import Wavefront OBJ files?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5064/batch-import-wavefront-obj/5065#5065).

---

To have it export only selected objects, comment line `7` and change line `11`.

```
# Remove
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
# Change to this where instead of the entire scene, we only look through selected objects
for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
```

or keep line `11` and add another line

```
for ob in scene.objects:
    # Add the check to see if in selected objects here
    if ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        # adjust indentation
        ...
        ...
```

***NB:*** Make sure the layers you have objects on are selected otherwise you will just get an empty file.

Comment: ok, thanks. And how i control options of export with your script (the scale, the axis...)?

Comment: @GabrielS all the options that you can pass to `bpy.ops.export_scene.obj` are here, http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/bpy.ops.export_scene.html#bpy.ops.export_scene.obj

Comment: @iKlsR, best only link to `_release` pages, we delete `blender_python_api_2_69_4` dirs occasionally.

Comment: @iKlsR your script work fine and i have custome it to fit what i want.
One more thing. how can i modify the script to export only selected objects?
Thanks

Comment: @GabrielS updated answer.

Comment: Maybe obvious to some, but I didn't realize for a bit that the layer had to be selected. Otherwise empty objects are exported.

Comment: @Sprunth Thanks for that, I'll take your word for it and update accordingly.

Comment: For anyone using Blender 2.8, use `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active` for the active object selection.

Answer (score 24):

Following Add-on allows to batch export the **current selection** or simply **all scene geometry objects as separate wavefront** `.obj` **files**. All usual options like *Apply Modifiers* or *Write Materials* are available in the *Properties Panel* <kbd>N</kbd> too.

**Repository**: [github.com/p2or/blender-batch-export-wavefront-obj](https://github.com/p2or/blender-batch-export-wavefront-obj)

[image]

#### [`io_batch_export_objs.py`](https://github.com/p2or/blender-batch-export-wavefront-obj/releases/download/0.5.0/io_batch_export_objs.py) (updated for 3.6+)

```
# ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#  Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
# ##### END GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
# <pep8 compliant>

bl_info = {
    "name": "OBJ Batch Export",
    "author": "p2or, brockmann, trippeljojo",
    "version": (0, 5, 0),
    "blender": (3, 6, 0),
    "location": "File > Import-Export",
    "description": "Export multiple OBJ files, their UVs and Materials",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "Import-Export"}


import bpy
import os
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper

from bpy.props import (BoolProperty,
                       IntProperty,
                       FloatProperty,
                       StringProperty,
                       EnumProperty,
                       CollectionProperty
                       )


class WM_OT_batchExportObjs(bpy.types.Operator, ExportHelper):
    """Batch export the scene to separate obj files"""
    bl_idname = "export_scene.batch_obj"
    bl_label = "Batch export OBJ's"
    bl_options = {'PRESET', 'UNDO'}

    # ExportHelper mixin class uses this
    filename_ext = ".obj"

    filter_glob = StringProperty(
            default="*.obj;*.mtl",
            options={'HIDDEN'},)

    selection_only: BoolProperty(
            name="Selection Only",
            description="Export selected objects only",
            default=True,)

    scale_factor: FloatProperty(
            name="Scale",
            min=0.01, max=1000.0,
            default=1.0,)
            
    axis_forward: EnumProperty(
            name="Forward Axis",
            items=(('X', "X", "Positive X Axis"),
                   ('Y', "Y", "Positive Y Axis"),
                   ('Z', "Z", "Positive Z Axis"),
                   ('NEGATIVE_X', "-X", "Negative X Axis"),
                   ('NEGATIVE_Y', "-Y", "Negative Y Axis"),
                   ('NEGATIVE_Z', "-Z (Default)", "Negative Z Axis"),),
            default='NEGATIVE_Z')
            
    axis_up: EnumProperty(
            name="Up Axis",
            items=(('X', "X Up", "Positive X Axis"),
                   ('Y', "Y Up (Default)", "Positive Y Axis"),
                   ('Z', "Z Up", "Positive Z Axis"),
                   ('NEGATIVE_X', "-X Up", "Negative X Axis"),
                   ('NEGATIVE_Y', "-Y Up", "Negative Y Axis"),
                   ('NEGATIVE_Z', "-Z Up", "Negative Z Axis"),),
            default='Y')

    modifiers_apply: BoolProperty(
            name="Apply Modifiers",
            description="Apply modifiers to exported meshes",
            default=False)
            
    eval_mode: EnumProperty(
            name="Properties",
            description="Determines properties like object visibility, "
                        "modifiers etc., where they differ for Render and Viewport",
            items=(('DAG_EVAL_VIEWPORT', 
                    "Viewport (Default)", 
                    "Export objects as they appear in the viewport"),
                   ('DAG_EVAL_RENDER', 
                    "Render", 
                    "Export objects as they appear in render"),),
            default='DAG_EVAL_VIEWPORT')
            
    # GEOMETRY 
    write_uvs: BoolProperty(
            name="UV Coordinates",
            description="Export the UV coordinates",
            default=True)

    write_normals: BoolProperty(
            name="Normals",
            description="Export per-face normals if the face is flat-shaded, "
                        "per-face-per-loop normals if smooth-shaded",
            default=True)
    
    write_colors: BoolProperty(
            name="Colors",
            description="Export per-vertex colors",
            default=False)

    triangulate_faces: BoolProperty(
            name="Triangulated Mesh",
            description='All ngons with four or more vertices will be triangulated. '
                        'Meshes in the scene will not be affected. Behaves like '
                        'Triangulate Modifier with ngon-method: "Beauty", quad-method: '
                        '"Shortest Diagonal", min vertices: 4.',
            default=False)
    
    write_nurbs: BoolProperty(
            name="Curves as NURBS",
            description="Export curves in parametric form instead of exporting as mesh",
            default=False)
        
    # MATERIALS 
    write_materials: BoolProperty(
            name="Export Materials",
            description="Export MTL library. There must be a Principled-BSDF "
                        "node for image textures to be exported to the MTL file.",
            default=True)
    
    write_pbr: BoolProperty(
            name="PBR Extensions",
            description="Export MTL library using PBR extensions (roughness, metallic, "
                        "sheen, coat, anisotropy, transmission)",
            default=False) 
    
    path_mode: EnumProperty(
            name="Path Mode",
            description="Method used to reference paths",
            items=(('AUTO', "Auto", "Use relative paths with subdirectories only"),
                   ('ABSOLUTE', "Absolute", "Always write absolute paths"),
                   ('RELATIVE', "Relative", "Write relative paths where possible"),
                   ('MATCH', "Match", "OMatch absolute/relative setting with input path"),
                   ('STRIP', "Strip", "Write filename only"),
                   ('COPY', "Copy", "Copy the file to the destination path"),
                   ),
            default='AUTO')
    
    # GROUPING 
    group_by_object: BoolProperty(
            name="Object Groups",
            description="Append mesh name to object name, separated by a '_'",
            default=False)
    
    group_by_material: BoolProperty(
            name="Material Groups",
            description="Generate an OBK group for each part of a geometry "
                        "using a different material",
            default=False)
    
    group_by_vertex: BoolProperty(
            name="Vertex Groups",
            description="Export the name of the vertex group of a face. "
                        "It is approximated by choosing the vertex group "
                        "with the most members amoung the vertices of a face",
            default=False)
    
    smoothing_groups: BoolProperty(
            name="Smooth Groups",
            description='Every smooth-shaded face is assigned group "1" and '
                        'every flat-shaded face "off".',
            default=False)

    smoothing_group_bitflags: BoolProperty(
            name="Smooth Group Bitflags",
            description="Same as 'Smooth Groups', but generate smooth groups IDs as bitflags "
                        "(produces at most 32 different smooth groups, usually much less)",
            default=False)

    def execute(self, context):
                       
        # Get the current folder
        folder_path = os.path.dirname(self.filepath)
        
        # Get all objects selected in the viewport
        viewport_selection = candidates = context.selected_objects
        if self.selection_only == False:
            candidates = [o for o in context.scene.objects]

        # Deselect all objects
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        
        for obj in [o for o in candidates if o.type == 'MESH']:
            obj.select_set(True)
            
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "{}.obj".format(obj.name))
            bpy.ops.wm.obj_export(
                    filepath=file_path,
                    export_animation=False,
                    #start_frame=-2147483648, 
                    # end_frame=2147483647,
                    forward_axis=self.axis_forward,
                    up_axis=self.axis_up,
                    global_scale=self.scale_factor,
                    apply_modifiers=self.modifiers_apply,
                    export_eval_mode=self.eval_mode,
                    export_selected_objects=True,
                    export_uv=self.write_uvs,
                    export_normals=self.write_normals,
                    export_colors=self.write_colors,
                    export_materials=self.write_materials,
                    export_pbr_extensions=self.write_pbr,
                    path_mode=self.path_mode,
                    export_triangulated_mesh=self.triangulate_faces,
                    export_curves_as_nurbs=self.write_nurbs,
                    export_object_groups=self.group_by_object,
                    export_material_groups=self.group_by_material,
                    export_vertex_groups=self.group_by_vertex,
                    export_smooth_groups=self.smoothing_groups,
                    smooth_group_bitflags=self.smoothing_group_bitflags
            )
            obj.select_set(False)

        # Restore Viewport Selection
        for obj in viewport_selection:
            obj.select_set(True)
            
        return {'FINISHED'}


def menu_func_import(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(WM_OT_batchExportObjs.bl_idname, text="Wavefront Batch (.obj)")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(WM_OT_batchExportObjs)
    #bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.append(menu_func_import)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WM_OT_batchExportObjs)
    #bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.remove(menu_func_import)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    #bpy.ops.export_scene.batch_obj('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

**Note:** The add-on is just a  wrapper of [`wm.obj_export()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.obj_export) or [`export_scene.obj()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.export_scene.html?highlight=bpy.ops.export_scene.obj#bpy.ops.export_scene.obj) operator in versions prior to Blender `3.2.0` until exporting multiple files is officially supported. To **import multiple obj files** see this answer: [How to batch import Wavefront OBJ files?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31825/3710)

#### Versions

To keep track of all the changes over the years I decided to create a [dedicated repository](https://github.com/p2or/blender-batch-export-wavefront-obj) instead of posting each version here, which makes it easier to download as well:

| Blender | Addon Version | Release |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Blender 2.74+ | 0.1.0 | [Download](https://github.com/p2or/blender-batch-export-wavefront-obj/releases/download/0.1.0/io_batch_export_objs.py) |
| Blender 2.80+ | 0.2.0 | [Download](https://github.com/p2or/blender-batch-export-wavefront-obj/releases/download/0.2.0/io_batch_export_objs.py) |
| Blender 3.1+ | 0.3.0 | [Download](https://github.com/p2or/blender-batch-export-wavefront-obj/releases/download/0.3.0/io_batch_export_objs.py) |
| Blender 3.3+ | 0.4.0 | [Download](https://github.com/p2or/blender-batch-export-wavefront-obj/releases/download/0.4.0/io_batch_export_objs.py) |
| Blender 3.6+ | 0.5.0 | [Download](https://github.com/p2or/blender-batch-export-wavefront-obj/releases/download/0.5.0/io_batch_export_objs.py) |

Comment: Is there a way to export the object with the center of object for the mesh instead of the global origin?

Comment: I figured it out, I [added a `use_mesh_as_center` option](https://gist.github.com/GammaGames/496a2a663af269c1383fa869d1100131) that sets the mesh's location to (0, 0, 0) before exporting and resets it back to its original after

Comment: Hi @p2or, thanks for the great answer. Do you know if there is a way to save modifiers along with the .obj, so that importing them later will preserve them? (I have a relevant question here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181143/create-mesh-in-scene-with-modifiers-export-and-save-it-then-load-later-with-mo)

Comment: [.obj is a pretty old file format](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_OBJ) and doesn't allow to preserve any modifiers. Even when using [alembic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alembic_(computer_graphics)) or [usd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Scene_Description), there is no way to preserve that (in 2020). If there is a serious reason to do that, I'd suggest to save all the modifier properties in a json string as text file and check for that file when loading the data back in. Cheers @ComputerScientist

Answer (score 5):

Working example for Blender 2.8 to batch export, just change the path

```
import bpy

#example path to store files
path = 'path\subpath\name'

#store selection
obs = bpy.context.selected_objects

for ob in obs:
    #deselect all but just one object and make it active
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    ob.select_set(state=True)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob

    #store object location then zero it out
    location = ob.location.copy()
    bpy.ops.object.location_clear()

    #export fbx
    filename = path + ob.name + '.obj'
    bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=filename, use_selection=True)

    #restore location
    ob.location = location

#reselect originally selected objects  
for ob in obs:
    ob.select_set(state=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

For me iKlsR's method did not work when trying to export multiple meshes. I got all meshes in the first exported file. The other exports were rather random, some contained nothing, others contained 3 objects. I have changed some code around and it works for me now.

---

**Method for exporting a selection.**

```
import bpy
import os

# get the current path and make a new folder for the exported meshes
path = bpy.path.abspath('//objs' + os.sep)
os.makedirs(path)

for object in bpy.context.selected_objects:

    # deselect all meshes
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    # select the object
    object.select = True

    # export object with its name as file name
    bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(
            filepath=path + object.name + '.obj',
            use_selection=True,
            )
```

Comment: thanks for directing me here.  I had to modify your version a little more to get it to work on OSX.  path = bpy.path.abspath('//')
#os.makedirs(path)

It was creating a folder but not putting the .obj files into it and it was also prefixing all the names with "objs/"

Also, it crashed upon second run unless I deleted the empty folder it's trying to re-create.

Comment: feel free edit my answer, however the code i posted worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For Blender 2.92.1

multiobj_exporter.py

```
import bpy
import os

basedir = 'absolute path'

sel_objs = [obj for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects if obj.type == 'MESH']
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
for obj in sel_objs:
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    obj.select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(
        filepath=os.path.join(basedir, obj.name + '.obj'),
        use_selection=True,
    )
    obj.select_set(False)
```

the code worked with only background option like below because an context error occurred.
If anyone know the reason why, please tell me.

$ blender --background --python multiobj_exporter.py

Answer (score -1):

Just Set This:
[image]

Untick All Other Settings And Set Only Obj Groups