# selecting many objects inside blender and export them as seperate .obj with one click?

Tags: mesh, export

I am currently working on a huge scene with modular building blocks and for the moment I have to export one object at the time which is extremely time consuming. Is it any way to select say 30 objects inside Blender and use the .obj exporter/some kind of script to export each object separate instead?

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5382/export-multiple-objects-to-obj?rq=1 (but that asks about all objects in the scene, not the selected only)

Comment: I've written an Add-on, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31852/3710, as usual you only have to enable **selection only**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

certainly! but it's a little hacky.  Run this from text editor for a few objects selected. Make sure to change the `folder` to a valid path.

```
import bpy
import os

folder = '/home/zeffii/Uploads/'

selected = bpy.context.selected_objects.copy()
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

for obj in selected:
    name = obj.name.replace('.', '_')
    obj.select = True
    fullpath = os.path.join(folder, name + '.obj')
    bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(
        filepath=fullpath, 
        check_existing=True, 
        axis_forward='-Z', 
        axis_up='Y', 
        use_selection=True, 
        use_animation=False, 
        use_mesh_modifiers=True, 
        use_edges=True, 
        use_smooth_groups=False, 
        use_smooth_groups_bitflags=False, 
        use_normals=True, 
        use_uvs=True, 
        use_materials=True, 
        use_triangles=False, 
        use_nurbs=False, 
        use_vertex_groups=False, 
        use_blen_objects=True, 
        group_by_object=False, 
        group_by_material=False, 
        keep_vertex_order=False, 
        global_scale=1, 
        path_mode='AUTO')
    obj.select = False
```

Most of those options in export_scene are default and you can remove those lines, or comment them out, but some of them may be useful if you want to change them later.

There's a nice Template for this in (with a slightly different approach - as in, it checks to see if the destination is valid first, which is handy if you aren't too familiar with *paths*): 
*TextEditor -> Templates -> Python -> Batch Export*

---

update:

https://gist.github.com/zeffii/529d435d5853e92dcc51

I'm not entirely sure how to inherit all the properties from the original exporter operator for objs. I could add them individually if you need specific props, else it would be wasted effort adding them all.

With the exporter code, you navigate to select a folder, don't have to type any thing, just hit the `Export selected Objects as obj` button at the end.

Comment: Big thanks! I will try it out and i will mark this solved if it worked.

Comment: Thanks but it didnt work, also i dont understand what the template is suppose to do, should i run that to check the validity of the filepath i write in some text inside the text editor? can you help me to write a script so that i can attach it to a shortcut instead? thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I almost finished the add-on code for it, which would let you pick a folder from a panel instead.

Comment: but in the meantime, you sould start blender from a console / prompt and try running the code, in order to get the error. ' it's not working ' is too vague

Comment: I've added a version of the script which when Run, in TextEditor will add a menu item to File -> Export. see the update

Comment: Thanks a ton for helping me with this! I really have no clue how to script and this will help me a lot in terms of time. I still havent tried the script, i will try it and if i get any errors i will paste it here as well. THANKS!

Comment: Okay i cant get it to work am i doing something wrong here? here you can see the screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vp8k4hgn3d7aab2/error.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24218/discussion-between-zeffii-and-jimmy-livefjord).

Comment: Funny, same idea :) Here you can find this as File Browser Add-on (user selection also implemented): http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31852/3710. Feel free to improve it.