# Auto-export to OBJ format on save

Tags: export

I have the following workflow in Blender:

- Edit object in .blend format
- Save .blend
- Set axis options in OBJ exporter
- Enable normals export in OBJ exporter
- Enable "triangulate" in OBJ exporter
- Export .obj (and .mtl) using OBJ exporter
- Copy .obj from wherever it got saved to `$someDir/mesh/`
- Copy .mtl from whetever it got saved to `$someDir/material/`

This is getting pretty tedious, so I'd like to write a Blender script so that when I press save, all of the above steps happen automatically. I couldn't figure out how to attach a script action to the "save" button. Is this possible?

(Note: I want to keep the native .blend file too)

Comment: You're better off running a script that saves the blend from inside the script. That would be easier than attaching a script to the save button.

Comment: You can find an OBJ export script on this SE answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31528/selecting-many-objects-inside-blender-and-export-them-as-seperate-obj-with-one/31529#31529

Answer (score 2):

Here's my answer with most of the script credit going to zeffii from [this page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31528/selecting-many-objects-inside-blender-and-export-them-as-seperate-obj-with-one/31529#31529). I just added the Save Blend file line at the top.

You can set the output path parent folder with the `folder` variable. The script creates the child mesh and material folders. The MTL files are moved to the material folder at the end of each OBJ loop.

```
import bpy
import os
import shutil

bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile() 


folder = '/path/to/export/folder/'
meshFolder = folder + 'mesh/'
matFolder = folder + 'material/'

if not os.path.exists(folder):
        os.makedirs(folder)
if not os.path.exists(meshFolder):
        os.makedirs(meshFolder)
if not os.path.exists(matFolder):
        os.makedirs(matFolder)        

selected = bpy.context.selected_objects.copy()
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

for obj in selected:
    name = obj.name.replace('.', '_')
    obj.select = True
    fullpath = os.path.join(meshFolder, name + '.obj')
    bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(
        filepath=fullpath, 
        check_existing=True, 
        axis_forward='-Z', 
        axis_up='Y', 
        use_selection=True, 
        use_animation=False, 
        use_mesh_modifiers=True, 
        use_edges=True, 
        use_smooth_groups=False, 
        use_smooth_groups_bitflags=False, 
        use_normals=True, 
        use_uvs=True, 
        use_materials=True, 
        use_triangles=False, 
        use_nurbs=False, 
        use_vertex_groups=False, 
        use_blen_objects=True, 
        group_by_object=False, 
        group_by_material=False, 
        keep_vertex_order=False, 
        global_scale=1, 
        path_mode='AUTO')
    obj.select = False
    shutil.move(meshFolder + name + '.mtl', matFolder + name + '.mtl')
```

Comment: you can add the copy command at the end to separate the mat and mesh, see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/123212/2987234

Comment: Yes, it depends how you want the OBJ and MTL files organized following export.

Comment: he has said that they should be separated

Comment: Thanks your right. Script has been updated to separate files and move the MTL files at the end of each loop increment.