# Exploding an OBJ file for export to 3DS

Tags: export, edit-mode

I have a file created in Delftship that I want to import into Sketchup. I exported it to a 3DS file but the file (3.27mb) crashes Sketchup every time. This has happened before and there is a part of the file that Sketchup does not like. I tried exporting to OBJ but the entire file takes forever and never loads into Sketchup. In the past I've been able to export to OBJ in pieces and that loads fine into Sketchup but I can't see how to explode this file. Selecting the model selects the entire model.

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31852/12 ?

Comment: Are you using blender for any of this?