# How can I use a script to export a model as a Wavefront file(.obj)?

Tags: python, scripting, export

I am interested in exporting finger model with texture as Wavefront file (.obj) using a script. Many scripts were available online but they provide only vertices or faces. It would be of great help if anyone could provide me a script to save the all the information on that model. The model is shown below:[image]

Comment: @someonewithpc- I am sorry, I wouldn't have asked this question if that solved my problem. I am looking for a script rather than doing it manually.

Comment: Oh, sorry.. I guess I misread your question

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5382/export-multiple-objects-to-obj