# How to isolate a single part. Blender to SolidWorks

Tags: export

my apologies in advance, im a total n00b to blender, i have NEVER used it before but a certain model i purchased has most likely been made with it, not 100% sure tho... I have the blender-file and atleast it opens up nicely.

I've been using SolidWorks for a while and im trying to convert the model into working in SolidWorks. Problem is, it has waaaay too much "facets" for SW to handle so it dies.

Plan B, i'l just do it piece by piece. The model seems to have several different parts in it and ive managed as much as move em around. A single part looks small enough for SW to handle so lets try that...

So, what i need a step-by-step quide in how to isolate a SINGLE part in the whole model into ONE file. Delete all others. I tried just smashing delete on all other parts, didnt work... Or i did something wrong.

I can then export that part as an STL file into SolidWorks and try to read all the parameters/features/etc. One part at a time.

So i have the entire model open in front of me, i click on a single part i want to isolate, delete ALL others, how do i do that?

Comment: There are a number of alternatives to reduce the number of faces. It all depends on the model. Can you edit your question and add a few images so that we understand what you are dealing with?

Comment: Wont that "simplify" the curves and shapes in the model if i were to reduce the faces?

Comment: see if this helps: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6184/splitting-pieces-of-a-mesh-into-a-new-object

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5382/export-multiple-objects-to-obj

Answer (score 1):

Open a new Blender and press <kbd>Shift F1</kbd>

find your file

then go into the object folder

and choose one.

You might also want to try and turn off the "subsurf" modifier if it has one

It would be in the Properties editor->modifiers

Comment: Object folder, where do i find that? There seems to be a dropdown menu with all sorts of "planes" and "circles" in it and they seem to affect the parts on screen somehow... 
Is that it?

Comment: What I was trying to tell you is how to "Append" an object from another file. "shift F1" is the shortcut . Here is a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3LsPcU69Vg

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the part you want to isolate.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to select everything but your original selection.
3. <kbd>X</kbd> >> <kbd>D</kbd> to delete those unwanted objects.
4. Do your export.
5. **DO NOT SAVE** Instead **File** >> **Recover Last Session**
6. Repeat for all desired items.

Also many exporters have a checkbox at the bottom left (when the Export screen pops up asking you where to save your file) that will just limit the export to what you have selected.  This may be worth looking for first.

See Below:

[image]