# Exporting as obj.All at once (noob question)

Tags: mesh, objects, export, blend-files

So i wanted to ask you guys if you can select all the objects you want to export all as different files.Instead of exporting one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google search yielded this
[Export multiple objects to .obj](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5382/export-multiple-objects-to-obj)

As expected it involves scripting, so not sure if it will work for you, but I don't think there's any way to do it natively through the GUI