# How to export selected objects using three.js exporter

Tags: python, three.js

I can find there is an option to export a single object or the entire scene, is there a way to export only the selected objects

Comment: What exporter are you using? Seems like one of them only exports selected objects anyway: https://github.com/satori99/threejs-blender-export

Answer (score 1):

To export multiple objects please check the answer made by @poor found [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31852/2517) very helpful and useful and you can edit the script to fit your needs.