# Updating batch export Script for Blender 2.80

Tags: python, scripting

I have an addon that works for 2.79 for batch exporting of .obj files, but now i'm looking to use 2.80, so trying to update the addon but no success. I've tried following a guide on YouTube with the API changes, but it's just not working. The original is below, and the changes i've made after.

```
import bpy
import os

from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper

from bpy.props import (BoolProperty,
                       FloatProperty,
                       StringProperty,
                       EnumProperty,
                       CollectionProperty
                       )

def highlightObjects(selection_list):
    for i in selection_list:
        bpy.data.objects[i.name].select = True

class ExportMultipleObjs(bpy.types.Operator, ExportHelper):
    """This appears in the tooltip of the operator and in the generated docs"""
    bl_idname = "export_scene.multiple_objs"
    bl_label = "Export multiple OBJ's"
    bl_options = {'PRESET', 'UNDO'}

    # ExportHelper mixin class uses this
    filename_ext = ".obj"

    filter_glob = StringProperty(
            default="*.obj;*.mtl",
            options={'HIDDEN'},
            )

    # List of operator properties, the attributes will be assigned
    # to the class instance from the operator setting before calling.

    # context group
    use_selection_setting = BoolProperty(
            name="Selection Only",
            description="Export selected objects only",
            default=True,
            )
    use_animation_setting = BoolProperty(
            name="Animation",
            description="Write out an OBJ for each frame",
            default=False,
            )

    # object group
    use_mesh_modifiers_setting = BoolProperty(
            name="Apply Modifiers",
            description="Apply modifiers (preview resolution)",
            default=False,
            )

    # extra data group
    use_edges_setting = BoolProperty(
            name="Include Edges",
            description="",
            default=False,
            )
    use_smooth_groups_setting = BoolProperty(
            name="Smooth Groups",
            description="Write sharp edges as smooth groups",
            default=True,
            )
    use_smooth_groups_bitflags_setting = BoolProperty(
            name="Bitflag Smooth Groups",
            description="Same as 'Smooth Groups', but generate smooth groups IDs as bitflags "
                        "(produces at most 32 different smooth groups, usually much less)",
            default=False,
            )
    use_normals_setting = BoolProperty(
            name="Write Normals",
            description="Export one normal per vertex and per face, to represent flat faces and sharp edges",
            default=False,
            )
    use_uvs_setting = BoolProperty(
            name="Include UVs",
            description="Write out the active UV coordinates",
            default=False,
            )
    use_materials_setting = BoolProperty(
            name="Write Materials",
            description="Write out the MTL file",
            default=False,
            )
    use_triangles_setting = BoolProperty(
            name="Triangulate Faces",
            description="Convert all faces to triangles",
            default=False,
            )
    use_nurbs_setting = BoolProperty(
            name="Write Nurbs",
            description="Write nurbs curves as OBJ nurbs rather than "
                        "converting to geometry",
            default=False,
            )
    use_vertex_groups_setting = BoolProperty(
            name="Polygroups",
            description="",
            default=False,
            )

    # grouping group
    use_blen_objects_setting = BoolProperty(
            name="Objects as OBJ Objects",
            description="",
            default=True,
            )
    group_by_object_setting = BoolProperty(
            name="Objects as OBJ Groups ",
            description="",
            default=False,
            )
    group_by_material_setting = BoolProperty(
            name="Material Groups",
            description="",
            default=False,
            )
    keep_vertex_order_setting = BoolProperty(
            name="Keep Vertex Order",
            description="",
            default=True,
            )

    axis_forward_setting = EnumProperty(
            name="Forward",
            items=(('X', "X Forward", ""),
                   ('Y', "Y Forward", ""),
                   ('Z', "Z Forward", ""),
                   ('-X', "-X Forward", ""),
                   ('-Y', "-Y Forward", ""),
                   ('-Z', "-Z Forward", ""),
                   ),
            default='-Z',
            )
    axis_up_setting = EnumProperty(
            name="Up",
            items=(('X', "X Up", ""),
                   ('Y', "Y Up", ""),
                   ('Z', "Z Up", ""),
                   ('-X', "-X Up", ""),
                   ('-Y', "-Y Up", ""),
                   ('-Z', "-Z Up", ""),
                   ),
            default='Y',
            )
    global_scale_setting = FloatProperty(
            name="Scale",
            min=0.01, max=1000.0,
            default=1.0,
            )

    def execute(self, context):                

        # get the folder
        folder_path = (os.path.dirname(self.filepath))

        # get objects selected in the viewport
        viewport_selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

        # get export objects
        obj_export_list = viewport_selection
        if self.use_selection_setting == False:
            obj_export_list = [i for i in bpy.context.scene.objects]

        # deselect all objects
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

        for item in obj_export_list:
            item.select = True
            if item.type == 'MESH':
                file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "{}.obj".format(item.name))
                bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=file_path, use_selection=True,
                                        axis_forward=self.axis_forward_setting, 
                                        axis_up=self.axis_up_setting,
                                        use_animation=self.use_animation_setting, 
                                        use_mesh_modifiers=self.use_mesh_modifiers_setting,
                                        use_edges=self.use_edges_setting, 
                                        use_smooth_groups=self.use_smooth_groups_setting,
                                        use_smooth_groups_bitflags=self.use_smooth_groups_bitflags_setting, 
                                        use_normals=self.use_normals_setting,
                                        use_uvs=self.use_uvs_setting, 
                                        use_materials=self.use_materials_setting, 
                                        use_triangles=self.use_triangles_setting, 
                                        use_nurbs=self.use_nurbs_setting, 
                                        use_vertex_groups=self.use_vertex_groups_setting, 
                                        use_blen_objects=self.use_blen_objects_setting, 
                                        group_by_object=self.group_by_object_setting, 
                                        group_by_material=self.group_by_material_setting, 
                                        keep_vertex_order=self.keep_vertex_order_setting, 
                                        global_scale=self.global_scale_setting)
            item.select = False

        # restore viewport selection
        highlightObjects(viewport_selection)

        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ExportMultipleObjs)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ExportMultipleObjs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    #bpy.ops.export_scene.multiple_objs('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

And here's what i've got so far. It's not giving any errors when running it, it's just not doing anyhting.

```
import bpy
import os

from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper

from bpy.props import (BoolProperty,
                       FloatProperty,
                       StringProperty,
                       EnumProperty,
                       CollectionProperty
                       )

def highlightObjects(selection_list):
    for i in selection_list:
        bpy.data.objects[i.name].select = True

class Export_OT_MultipleObjs(bpy.types.Operator, ExportHelper):
    """This appears in the tooltip of the operator and in the generated docs"""
    bl_idname = "export_scene.multiple_objs"
    bl_label = "Export multiple OBJ's"
    bl_options = {'PRESET', 'UNDO'}

    # ExportHelper mixin class uses this
    filename_ext = ".obj"

    filter_glob : StringProperty(
            default="*.obj;*.mtl",
            options={'HIDDEN'},
            )

    # List of operator properties, the attributes will be assigned
    # to the class instance from the operator setting before calling.

    # context group
    use_selection_setting : BoolProperty(
            name="Selection Only",
            description="Export selected objects only",
            default=True,
            )
    use_animation_setting : BoolProperty(
            name="Animation",
            description="Write out an OBJ for each frame",
            default=False,
            )

    # object group
    use_mesh_modifiers_setting : BoolProperty(
            name="Apply Modifiers",
            description="Apply modifiers (preview resolution)",
            default=False,
            )

    # extra data group
    use_edges_setting : BoolProperty(
            name="Include Edges",
            description="",
            default=False,
            )
    use_smooth_groups_setting : BoolProperty(
            name="Smooth Groups",
            description="Write sharp edges as smooth groups",
            default=True,
            )
    use_smooth_groups_bitflags_setting : BoolProperty(
            name="Bitflag Smooth Groups",
            description="Same as 'Smooth Groups', but generate smooth groups IDs as bitflags "
                        "(produces at most 32 different smooth groups, usually much less)",
            default=False,
            )
    use_normals_setting : BoolProperty(
            name="Write Normals",
            description="Export one normal per vertex and per face, to represent flat faces and sharp edges",
            default=False,
            )
    use_uvs_setting : BoolProperty(
            name="Include UVs",
            description="Write out the active UV coordinates",
            default=False,
            )
    use_materials_setting : BoolProperty(
            name="Write Materials",
            description="Write out the MTL file",
            default=False,
            )
    use_triangles_setting : BoolProperty(
            name="Triangulate Faces",
            description="Convert all faces to triangles",
            default=False,
            )
    use_nurbs_setting : BoolProperty(
            name="Write Nurbs",
            description="Write nurbs curves as OBJ nurbs rather than "
                        "converting to geometry",
            default=False,
            )
    use_vertex_groups_setting : BoolProperty(
            name="Polygroups",
            description="",
            default=False,
            )

    # grouping group
    use_blen_objects_setting : BoolProperty(
            name="Objects as OBJ Objects",
            description="",
            default=True,
            )
    group_by_object_setting : BoolProperty(
            name="Objects as OBJ Groups ",
            description="",
            default=False,
            )
    group_by_material_setting : BoolProperty(
            name="Material Groups",
            description="",
            default=False,
            )
    keep_vertex_order_setting : BoolProperty(
            name="Keep Vertex Order",
            description="",
            default=True,
            )

    axis_forward_setting : EnumProperty(
            name="Forward",
            items=(('X', "X Forward", ""),
                   ('Y', "Y Forward", ""),
                   ('Z', "Z Forward", ""),
                   ('-X', "-X Forward", ""),
                   ('-Y', "-Y Forward", ""),
                   ('-Z', "-Z Forward", ""),
                   ),
            default='-Z',
            )
    axis_up_setting : EnumProperty(
            name="Up",
            items=(('X', "X Up", ""),
                   ('Y', "Y Up", ""),
                   ('Z', "Z Up", ""),
                   ('-X', "-X Up", ""),
                   ('-Y', "-Y Up", ""),
                   ('-Z', "-Z Up", ""),
                   ),
            default='Y',
            )
    global_scale_setting : FloatProperty(
            name="Scale",
            min=0.01, max=1000.0,
            default=1.0,
            )

    def execute(self, context):                

        # get the folder
        folder_path = (os.path.dirname(self.filepath))

        # get objects selected in the viewport
        viewport_selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

        # get export objects
        obj_export_list = viewport_selection
        if self.use_selection_setting == False:
            obj_export_list = [i for i in bpy.context.scene.objects]

        # deselect all objects
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

        for item in obj_export_list:
            item.select = True
            if item.type == 'MESH':
                file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "{}.obj".format(item.name))
                bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=file_path, use_selection=True,
                                        axis_forward=self.axis_forward_setting, 
                                        axis_up=self.axis_up_setting,
                                        use_animation=self.use_animation_setting, 
                                        use_mesh_modifiers=self.use_mesh_modifiers_setting,
                                        use_edges=self.use_edges_setting, 
                                        use_smooth_groups=self.use_smooth_groups_setting,
                                        use_smooth_groups_bitflags=self.use_smooth_groups_bitflags_setting, 
                                        use_normals=self.use_normals_setting,
                                        use_uvs=self.use_uvs_setting, 
                                        use_materials=self.use_materials_setting, 
                                        use_triangles=self.use_triangles_setting, 
                                        use_nurbs=self.use_nurbs_setting, 
                                        use_vertex_groups=self.use_vertex_groups_setting, 
                                        use_blen_objects=self.use_blen_objects_setting, 
                                        group_by_object=self.group_by_object_setting, 
                                        group_by_material=self.group_by_material_setting, 
                                        keep_vertex_order=self.keep_vertex_order_setting, 
                                        global_scale=self.global_scale_setting)
            item.select = False

        # restore viewport selection
        highlightObjects(viewport_selection)

        return {'FINISHED'}

classes = ( Export_OT_MultipleObjs )

register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    #bpy.ops.export_scene.multiple_objs('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

What else needs to be changed? Thanks

Comment: Updated the addon for 2.8x: [Export multiple objects to .obj](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5382/export-multiple-objects-to-obj)

Comment: @brockmann I didn't know where it originally came from, but this is exactly what I needed. The changes I made were subtle, but this has it all. Thank you for linking this.

Comment: Glad I could help @AS

Comment: @brockmann By any chance did you also do the mass import script too?

Comment: Looks like that's already done, see the link at the bottom of p2or's answer.

Comment: I see it, thank you very much. Appreciate the help.