# How to export obj file with different mesh

Tags: export

I have a simple bottle with cap. I have exported the mesh with obj file. Importing in After effect with 3d element plugin i get only single mesh. How to have a separate mesh. Any option while exporting.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to enable *"Objects as OBJ objects"* and see whether that works for element3d. Otherwise have a look into [Export multiple objects to .obj](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5382/export-multiple-objects-to-obj)

Comment: @brockmann sorry did not get what u mean enable objects as obj objects?

Comment: *File > Export OBJ > N (properties panel as usual) > Objects as OBJ Objects*

Comment: @brockmann i tried did not work. i have attach the file.

Comment: Then use the script to export single files... as suggested before

Comment: @brockmann Thanks with the script its working