# FBX export operator - How can I change the scaling mode?

Tags: python, scripting, export

I want to change the scaling mode in blender

[image]

based on [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.83/bpy.ops.export_scene.html) I can do it:

**apply_unit_scale**

```
apply_unit_scale (boolean, (optional)) – Apply Unit, Take into account current Blender units settings (if unset, raw Blender Units values are used as-is)
```

**apply_scale_options**

```
apply_scale_options (enum in ['FBX_SCALE_NONE', 'FBX_SCALE_UNITS', 'FBX_SCALE_CUSTOM', 'FBX_SCALE_ALL'], (optional)) –
```

I tried to change the scaling mode to **unit scaling** in blender but I don't know why it didn't work

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(apply_unit_scale=True)
bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(apply_scale_options='FBX_SCALE_UNITS')
```

I have this error in the console:

[image]

I also tried to copy and paste the example in the console but I have same error!:

```
bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath="", check_existing=True, filter_glob="*.fbx", use_selection=False, use_active_collection=False, global_scale=1.0, apply_unit_scale=True, apply_scale_options='FBX_SCALE_NONE', bake_space_transform=False, object_types={'ARMATURE', 'CAMERA', 'EMPTY', 'LIGHT', 'MESH', 'OTHER'}, use_mesh_modifiers=True, use_mesh_modifiers_render=True, mesh_smooth_type='OFF', use_subsurf=False, use_mesh_edges=False, use_tspace=False, use_custom_props=False, add_leaf_bones=True, primary_bone_axis='Y', secondary_bone_axis='X', use_armature_deform_only=False, armature_nodetype='NULL', bake_anim=True, bake_anim_use_all_bones=True, bake_anim_use_nla_strips=True, bake_anim_use_all_actions=True, bake_anim_force_startend_keying=True, bake_anim_step=1.0, bake_anim_simplify_factor=1.0, path_mode='AUTO', embed_textures=False, batch_mode='OFF', use_batch_own_dir=True, use_metadata=True, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y')
```

Comment: You can. However, you would have to specify a valid file path in order to make it work.

Comment: You need to set the file path where you want to store the output.

Comment: Something like: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169537/exporting-multiple-meshes-individually-at-once/169820#169820 ?

Comment: @brockmann yes exactly thank you!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6174/15543

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh sorry for this stupid question
as Robert Gützkow and brockmann mentioned I didn't set the path

```
import bpy

#example path to store files
path = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")

#export fbx
filename = path + 'Test.fbx'
bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=filename, use_selection=True,apply_scale_options='FBX_SCALE_UNITS',apply_unit_scale=True)
```

> os.path.join() method in Python join one or more path components
> intelligently. This method concatenates various path components with
> exactly one directory separator (‘/’) following each non-empty part
> except the last path component. If the last path component to be
> joined is empty then a directory seperator (‘/’) is put at the end.

```
import bpy

# importing os module  
import os 
  
    
#example path to store files
path = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")

# Join various path components  
filename = os.path.join(path, 'Test.fbx')
    
bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=filename, use_selection=True,apply_scale_options='FBX_SCALE_UNITS',apply_unit_scale=True)
```

Instead of setting path manually, I use this [solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169537/exporting-multiple-meshes-individually-at-once/169820#169820)

Comment: Recommend use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) or have a look into [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) if you haven't already.

Comment: @brockmann thank you. I actually don't want to set the path manually is there a way to set the path by the browser for export_scene.fbx?

Comment: Pass `"INVOKE_DEFAULT"` as first argument. See [Execution Context](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#execution-context) in the API docs. This will open the file browser with the settings applied, but you still need to select the location.

Comment: Depends how the UI should look like and where do you want to have it. In general such basic questions have an answer here already, just search for it *or* explain in detail what you'd like to get and why other answers are bad @SeyedMortezaKamali