# How can I make a custom fbx exporter for unity?

Tags: python, unity

I want to export fbx for unity based on [manual way in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpH5ZfonExo) I know there is an option as `!!EXPERIMENTAL!!`, I don't want to use it because sometimes it doesn't work.

[image]

## Manual Way

manual way works fine I just want to do manual way by code.
because I have to repeat these steps on every 3d models!!!

suppose we have a fish model and we want to export it to untiy

[image]

1.Manually rotate the object by -90 degree around X-axis
(if you don't see this panel - press N key)

[image]

2.press Ctrl + A and Apply => Rotation

[image]

3.and set X rotation to 90 degrees
(do not apply this time)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make steps automatic

1.rotate the object by -90 degree around X-axis

```
obj.rotation_euler = (math.radians(-90),0,0)
```

2.press Ctrl + A and Apply => Rotation

```
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=True, scale=False)
```

3.and set X rotation to 90 degrees
(do not apply this time)

```
obj.rotation_euler = (math.radians(-90),0,0)
```

also, you can export it by [unit scale](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192050/fbx-export-operator-how-can-i-change-the-scaling-mode/192052#192052)

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Unity Fix",
    "author": "Kamali",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "File > Export > Export For Unity",
    "description": "Fix Pivot ,Location , Rotation , Scale ",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "",
}


import bpy
import math

def write_some_data(context, filepath):
    bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_MASS', center='MEDIAN')
    obj= context.object
    
    # reset location to the center
    obj.location = (0,0,0)
    
    # reset everything to make sure it won't change
    bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=True, rotation=True, scale=True)
    # set rotation to -90
    
    obj.rotation_euler = (math.radians(-90),0,0)
    # reset everything
    bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=True, rotation=True, scale=True)
    
    # rotate 90 degree along x axis
    obj.rotation_euler = (math.radians(90),0,0)
    
    
    # apply unit scaling
    bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=filepath, use_selection=True,apply_scale_options='FBX_SCALE_UNITS',apply_unit_scale=True)
    return {'FINISHED'}

    


from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper
from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty, EnumProperty
from bpy.types import Operator


class ExportSomeData(Operator, ExportHelper):
    """Export For Unity"""
    bl_idname = "export_test.some_data"  
    bl_label = "Export For Unity"


    filename_ext = ".fbx"

    filter_glob: StringProperty(
        default="*.fbx",
        options={'HIDDEN'},
        maxlen=255, 
    )


    def execute(self, context):
        return write_some_data(context, self.filepath)


# Only needed if you want to add into a dynamic menu
def menu_func_export(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ExportSomeData.bl_idname, text="Export For Unity")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ExportSomeData)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.append(menu_func_export)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ExportSomeData)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.remove(menu_func_export)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]