# Export multiple .MDD at once?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, export, file-format

I have 97 `MDD` files created from different meshes (armature deformed, cloth deformed etc). **Is there a way to select multiple meshes and export them as individual `MDD` files?**

I have seen that there's another post which provides an add-on to export selected objects to `FBX`, but unfortunately I do not have the skills adapting it to work for `MDD` files: [Exporting multiple meshes individually at once](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169537/exporting-multiple-meshes-individually-at-once)

*My progress so far:* I've found someone trying to export multiple `MDD` at once on another forum, and it seems that there's a Python command line to export a `MDD`: `bpy.ops.export_shape.mdd(fps=24, frame_start=1, frame_end=250)`. Also, there's a python template for Batch exporting:

```
import bpy
import os

# export to blend file location
basedir = os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath)

if not basedir:
    raise Exception("Blend file is not saved")

view_layer = bpy.context.view_layer

obj_active = view_layer.objects.active
selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

for obj in selection:

    obj.select_set(True)

    # some exporters only use the active object
    view_layer.objects.active = obj

    name = bpy.path.clean_name(obj.name)
    fn = os.path.join(basedir, name)

    bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=fn + ".fbx", use_selection=True)

    # Can be used for multiple formats
    # bpy.ops.export_scene.x3d(filepath=fn + ".x3d", use_selection=True)

    obj.select_set(False)

    print("written:", fn)


view_layer.objects.active = obj_active

for obj in selection:
    obj.select_set(True)
```

**How can I export multiple .MDD files ?**

Comment: Is there any mdd exporter already? If so you just have to replace `export_scene.fbx()` operator and all corresponding properties/arguments.

Comment: @brockmann (I deleted my answer and edited my original post). What do you mean ? Yes, there's a .mdd exporter built in Blender but no option for Batch exporting is displayed. As I said, I don't understand how Python works, and replacing the ".fbx" by ".mdd" gives me an error. Also, I don't know any Python functions, neither specific .mdd arguments. So I need help here, I guess mixing the Batch Export template with the specific .mdd exporting function will do the trick ?

Comment: Modified the code of the linked answer: https://pasteall.org/UhqR Make sure the other mdd exporter is enabled, run the code in the text editor, please test and report back.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. Yes, the MDD exporter add-on is enabled. Copy/Pasted the code in the text editor, saved it and hitted run : bpy.ops.text.run_script() in the system console aand.. that's it. Nothing else happens, no .mdd output in the directory, no loading time after hitting the Play button :/

Comment: Go to *File > Export > Batch export mdd* to execute the process (as usual).

Comment: Oh okay sorry, as I said I'm a complete noob about Python and scripting... Okay I got an error trying to run the Batch export in File > Export, because "fps" is not a property off .mdd exporter, so I've just replaced "fps=self.fps" by "fps=self.frames_per_second" line 120 and after running the script again, everything worked perfect ! Thanks you very much sir ! :)
Last question, how can I remove a previous ran script from my Export list in Blender? (The first one gave me the error I was just talking about so it is not usable)

Comment: Cool. If that's working, save the file to something like `my_batch_mdd.py` from the text editor, close blender, start blender, go the user preferences > add-ons, click on *Install Add-on*, select the file, enable it, done.

Comment: Maybe you could post your code as an answer so that I can accept it ? Then it would be easier for anyone else to find it, even when the pasteall links will expire ? Anyway, thank you again for your help (I saw that you were also the savior guy in the .fbx batch export haha) :)

Comment: Ops we're crossing answers.
Okay instruction clear, I'll do that. Thank you again ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addon based on [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31852/31447), adapted to export all *objects in selection* to single `.mdd` files. Make sure 'NewTekk MDD format' add-on is enabled and [install the add-on as usual](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/installing-an-addon):

[image]

#### `batch_mdd_export.py`

```
# ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#  Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
# ##### END GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
# <pep8 compliant>
​
bl_info = {
    "name": "Batch export MDD files",
    "author": "brockmann",
    "version": (0, 1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "File > Import-Export",
    "description": "Batch Export Objects in Selection to MDD",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "Import-Export"}
​
​
import bpy
import os
​
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper
​
from bpy.props import (BoolProperty,
                       FloatProperty,
                       IntProperty,
                       StringProperty,
                       EnumProperty,
                       CollectionProperty
                       )
​
​
class Batch_MDD_Export(bpy.types.Operator, ExportHelper):
    """Batch export objects to fbx files"""
    bl_idname = "export_scene.batch_mdd"
    bl_label = "Batch export MDD"
    bl_options = {'PRESET', 'UNDO'}
​
    # ExportHelper mixin class uses this
    filename_ext = ".mdd"
​
    filter_glob : StringProperty(
            default="*.mdd",
            options={'HIDDEN'},
            )
​
    # List of operator properties, the attributes will be assigned
    # to the class instance from the operator setting before calling.
    
    # Context group
    use_selection_setting: BoolProperty(
            name="Selection Only",
            description="Export selected objects only",
            default=True,
            )
​
    use_rest_frame: BoolProperty(
            name="Use Rest Frame",
            description="ToDo",
            default=False,
            )
            
    frames_per_second: FloatProperty(
            name="FPS",
            description="ToDo",
            min=1, max=60,
            default=25,
            )
​
    frame_start: IntProperty(
            name="Frame Start",
            description="ToDo",
            default=1,
            )
    
    frame_end: IntProperty(
            name="Frame End",
            description="ToDo",
            default=250,
            )
            
    def execute(self, context):                
​
        # get the folder
        folder_path = os.path.dirname(self.filepath)
​
        # get objects selected in the viewport
        viewport_selection = context.selected_objects
​
        # get export objects
        obj_export_list = viewport_selection
        if self.use_selection_setting == False:
            obj_export_list = [i for i in context.scene.objects]
​
        # deselect all objects
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
​
        for item in obj_export_list:
            item.select_set(True)
            if item.type == 'MESH':
                context.view_layer.objects.active = item # Set active object
                file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "{}.mdd".format(item.name))
​
                # MDD settings
                bpy.ops.export_shape.mdd(
                        filepath=file_path,
                        fps=self.frames_per_second,
                        frame_start=self.frame_start,
                        frame_end=self.frame_end
                        )
​
            item.select_set(False)
​
        # restore viewport selection
        for ob in viewport_selection:
            ob.select_set(True)
​
        return {'FINISHED'}
​
​
# Only needed if you want to add into a dynamic menu
def menu_func_import(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(Batch_MDD_Export.bl_idname, text="MDD Batch Export (.mdd)")
​
​
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Batch_MDD_Export)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.append(menu_func_import)
​
​
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Batch_MDD_Export)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.remove(menu_func_import)
​
​
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
​
    # test call
    #bpy.ops.export_scene.batch_mdd('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

I added all possible arguments of the 'lightwave point cache' operator `export_shape.mdd()`, see line `117`. You can change them or add new properties to the operator, wasn't sure.

Comment: Hey, just giving you a feedback : it seems that this script exports the same mesh (the active one, so the first one) over and over. In my case I have the same .mdd for 97 times. I understand that the "for" is used to do an incremental .mdd export but I was not able to find how to correct it. Could you give it a try ? Sorry to ask for your help again :/

Comment: Oh and I forgot to mention that the names are correctly set !

Comment: Not sure I can properly test the output since I don't have access to Lightwave. Might be necessary to set the current object to the active one, updated the code: https://pasteall.org/2ukq Does that work? @Pdhm

Comment: First, thanks for helping me in such an efficient way, I really appreciate it.
Secondly : YES it worked ! :) I tested it on three .mdd exports for a limited amount of frames but it worked. I'll give a try over a lot more now but I need an hour of calculation. Will update you in a couple of hours. Again, thank you very much !