# Python - Check all objects have material assigned before export?

Tags: python, export

Is there a way to check (or warning the user) if all objects in the scene have a material assigned, before exporting?

Or any other solution I could use?

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi and welcome! Sure. What do you want to export? File format? Do you mind adding the current state of your code? Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @brockmann Thanks in advance. I'm exporting meshes on .FBX format. I know how to check if It has material or not assigned, but I don't know how to warning the user BEFORE the export. Something like: "You're exporting materials without material assigned. Do you want to proceed?"

Is it possible?

Thanks again!

Comment: Yep: [How to call a confirmation dialog box?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73286/how-to-call-a-confirmation-dialog-box) I recommend edit your question accordingly...

Comment: @brockmann Thanks. And how do I call this dialog box before the export. I mean, press the File-> Export -> .fbx  and in this moment call my script (before showing the export window)

Is it possible?

Comment: You would have to create your own custom operator like: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/169820/31447 and add an invoke method (as described in the answer above). Don't think that's worth it TBH