# Is there a working io_export_batch_obj.py for Blender 2.83+?

Tags: scripting, export, import

i just stumbled across this information about a script for multi export, and there has to be an import too. But all the scripts from the answers here don't work for me:
[Export multiple objects to .obj](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5382/export-multiple-objects-to-obj)

I guess it's because of the new design and layout?! But is someone working on a newer version of these multi export and import scripts?!

Comment: What *exactly* is not working? Tested... Copy, paste the addon from https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31852 into a new text document, run the script, go to *File > Export > Wavefront Batch*... or install as add-on.

Comment: It's just not there, not like in the picture, not like in File > Export > Wavefront Batch...
But the log tells me that the installation was a success. So i thought it is just outdated. I also did not find it in the addons section!
But it is working now. I tried to install it again, with the same file i created before. Then i searched manually in the addon section again and there it was... Now it is working. So thank you for testing the script!

Comment: I updated the script for 2.8 so... In blender, switch to the scripting workspace, create a new text document, paste the code and run the script. Again, just tested, no issues.

Comment: It's alright now. I tried it again, then it worked. I myself created with the copied code a .py file in notepad++. It just did not work somehow. Like i said, i used the same file from an hour ago just now and it just worked. Just did everything the same, like always, when installing addons. No clue why it was not working first...

Comment: Cool... glad it worked @Roland