# How to make object A a parent of object B via Blender's Python API?

Tags: python, objects, parent

I have two objects each of them hold in a variable. Now I want to parent them so object `A` is the parent of object `B`. How can I do this using Blender's Python API? I know there is a `parent_set` operator in Blender but I don't know how to set up the selection in the scene via Python so I just have to call

```
bpy.ops.object.parent_set(...)
```

---

It looks like there is a parent attribute on objects which I can use like

```
b.parent = a
```

How can I use that?

Answer (score 28):

Avoid all the dancing around using `bpy.ops` and that setting *selection* and *active*. Most of those bpy.ops commands are meant to be called by the UI once a user clicks a ' parent to x ' button , etc.

You are on the right path by using the `.parent`  attribute. All you really need are the names or references to the objects and you can parent much, much simpler.

```
import bpy

objects = bpy.data.objects
a = objects['Cube']
b = objects['Cube.001']
b.parent = a
```

There are times using a bpy.ops is a reasonable solution, but in this case the lower level solution of using `b.parent = a` is functionally equivalent and fewer lines of code.

#### Edit

In the comments of this answer we discuss how to decide when to use a member of bpy.ops, but CoDEmanX has a [fine clarification here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7360/47)

Comment: Right, in which cases do you think it makes sense to use the operator?

Comment: When there is no low level alternative, or the low level alternative is very involved. Then it's a showdown between how much effort you want to put into getting the context right for the operators and time spent writing the low level solution.

Comment: Ok thanks zeffii - could you add this to the answer please - I think this could be helpful :)

Comment: @poor, for instance we see a tonne of people trying to bake sound using the operato (and a lot of ugly code trying to set context) r, it would make sense to have that as a separate util function or even command line tool, If people are really serious they would use that instead to bake the graph

Comment: You are right, but on the other hand it's easy for beginners to dive into it... Anyway, thanks for editing the answer! +2 if I could :)

Comment: This doesn't not behave equally to `bpy.ops.object.parent_set`. When using the `bpy.ops` API, everything is as expected. However, when setting `a.parent = b`, a strange transformation is applied to the child object. Any idea?

Comment: @schlamar it's worth asking a separate question about the difference. so it doesn't get tucked away in the comment section of this question.

Comment: @schlamar did you ask about this problem with low-level parenting? The transformation added is very annoying and there should be some simple method of avoiding it. Please let me know where can I find this solution.

Answer (score 22):

**If the child object moves after setting the parent**, use the following to move it back:

```
# After both parent and child have been link()ed to the scene:
childObject.parent = parentObject
childObject.matrix_parent_inverse = parentObject.matrix_world.inverted()
```

To **unparent** and keep the child object location (without using operators):

```
parented_wm = childObject.matrix_world.copy()
childObject.parent = None
childObject.matrix_world = parented_wm
```

As mentioned in the comments, the matrices need to be up to date, which can be done with `bpy.context.scene.update()`

Comment: Or bpy.ops.object.parent_no_inverse_set()

Comment: One thing to note, that wasn't immediately obvious (but maybe should have been), is that if you have also added the objects `childObject` and `parentObject` programatically you may have to perform a `bpy.context.scene.update()` prior to this answer's code before you will be able to access the correct matrix values.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @RayMairlot. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can use b.parent = a but you can of course use :

```
bpy.ops.object.parent_set()
```

I made a little code for this:

```
import bpy

a = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
b = bpy.data.objects['Cube.001']

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') #deselect all object

a.select = True
b.select = True     #select the object for the 'parenting'

bpy.context.scene.objects.active = a    #the active object will be the parent of all selected object

bpy.ops.object.parent_set()

#Now The parent of b is a
```

For setting the parameter of the parent_set you can go to the [blender python api](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_60_0/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.parent_set).
Blender also give you this in the python console :

```
parent_set()
bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='OBJECT', xmirror=False, keep_transform=False)
```

Comment: One should use `.parent = ...`, see [Q: Python performance with Blender operators](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/python-performance-with-blender-operators)

Answer (score 3):

lucblender answer was helpfull but I got errors with blender 2.83
here's a working code :

```
import bpy

a = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
b = bpy.data.objects['Cube.001']

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') # deselect all object

a.select_set(True)
b.select_set(True)     # select the object for the 'parenting'

bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = a    # the active object will be the parent of all selected object

bpy.ops.object.parent_set()

# Now The parent of b is a
```

Comment: Hi. Please don't use the answer option to ask new questions. Instead, ask a new question and post a link to this original question.

Comment: Hello, it's not a question, it's a fix to the previous answer which is not working anymore in 2.83