# how to set the camera follow path using python script

Tags: bezier-curves, camera, path

(suppose camera is in the right location already)

I understand if doing this manually I need to select the camera and hold shift and select the curve that I want to follow, then ctrl+p and select "follow path".
But how do I make this with python script?

My guess is I can use python script to implement these tow steps in order. It seems that "Follow path" can be achieved by

```
bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='FOLLOW')
```

But this alone won't work.

sorry I'm a newbie to blender.

Comment: related: [make object A a parent ob object B via Python](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9200/make-object-a-a-parent-ob-object-b-via-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for @poor 's comment. It can be done in the way of

[make object A a parent of object B via Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9200/make-object-a-a-parent-ob-object-b-via-python)

specifically, it needs to be coded like:

```
camera = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
path = bpy.data.objects['NurbsPath']
lamp = bpy.data.objects['Lamp']

camera.select = True
lamp.select = True
path.select = True

bpy.context.scene.objects.active = path #parent

bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='FOLLOW') #follow path
```

you can find the objects name in python console with

```
list(bpy.data.objects)
```