# Trying to select updated mesh, but get: Object 'Plane' can't be selected because it is not in View Layer 'View Layer'!

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, scene, viewlayers

Using Blender 2.82a, I am trying to advance an animation and then select an object or mesh that has been updated. I am using something similar to the old `scene.update()` (pre-2.8) as described in the [Blender Wiki here](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Scene_and_Object_API) and [this question here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140789/what-is-the-replacement-for-scene-update). However, I am not sure how to properly select the object. Here is a minimal working example. I make a cloth above the starting cube. I advance several frames. Then, I use `evaluated_get` to get the updated cloth.

But now I'm trying to select it using `select_set` so that I can then make it the child of an armature ([using code in this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9204/75918)). If you run this Python script:

```
import bpy

# Add collision modifier to starting cube to support cloth.
cube_obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='COLLISION')

# Make cloth at a height above the cube.
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(location=(0, 0, 2.0))
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(number_cuts=20)
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='CLOTH')
cloth = bpy.context.object

# Advance some frames to apply physics.
bpy.context.scene.frame_set(0)
scene = bpy.context.scene
for f in range(1, 10):
    scene.frame_set(f)

# Get updated cloth.
depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
cloth_upd = cloth.evaluated_get(depsgraph)

# At this point, bpy.context.selected_objects = [bpy.data.objects['Plane']]
# Now try to select the _updated_ cloth, but this does not work. I do this because
# I will make an armature later, which is the parent of this updated cloth.
cloth_upd.select_set(True)
```

I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: Error: Object 'Plane' can't be selected because it is not in View Layer 'View Layer'!
```

When I print the `cloth` and `cloth_upd`, both result in `<bpy_struct, Object("Plane")>`, suggesting that they are of the same class. Does anyone know how to properly select the updated mesh or adjust the layer?

Comment: Thanks Ray for the better tags! Still getting used to them here. :)

Comment: i) since it was last added will already be selected ii) as mentioned before adding a grid removes need to editmode toggle and subdivide a plane to get same result iii) why select the (already selected) updated object?

Comment: Hi @batFINGER Thanks for clarity regarding (i) and (ii). I am doing this because if I use the original `cloth` and try to pin vertices, then the vertices will be pinned *as if they were from frame 0* (and not a later frame after physics/animation is applied). This is a limitation that I have been trying to wrap my head around for two weeks. :)  I put in a more extensive example here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180199/pin-cloth-vertices-at-a-specific-set-of-frames-and-un-pin-otherwise-in-python . Do you feel like this approach makes sense or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: There is no need to use an operator to set the object parent, see [comment below linked answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9200/how-to-make-object-a-a-parent-of-object-b-via-blenders-python-api/9204#comment14997_9204)  Can simply `ob.parent = parent` and set parent inverse  matrices if need be. removing the need to select.  Similarly would never use the add modifiers op.  Think  of an evaluated object as a "virtual entity"  for that frame    If you `print(repr(ob))` instead will see one as bpy.data.objects["Foo"] one as  "Evaluated Object Foo"   I doubt whether

Comment: changing the relations of an evaluated object is going to work, or work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks @batFINGER. I now know how to make a grid (so as to remove edit mode toggle) and also to make parenting easier without the use of an operator. I also confirm I see the difference in `print(repr(ob))` with the object vs the evaluated object (or virtual entity). I am wondering if it's possible to "convert" from an evaluated object to a normal object so that we can create an object with the updated positions? (I can ask this as a separate question if you feel this would be too long for a comment.) Or is this an ill-posed question?

Comment: Just did some experiments, I can run the `.original` attribute from an evaluated object to get the original one. Unfortunately these will be based on the location at frame 0 upon creation, rather than with updated locations based on later frames.