# How to update world transformation matrices without calling a scene update

Tags: python, matrix, depsgraph

I have a Python script that's recursively parenting children objects to parents. I can use bpy.ops.object.parent_set(), which produces the desired outcome but is too slow for what I'm doing.

Another solution I found was to not call bpy.ops, but rather to set the parent directly, as outlined in [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/72899/12805) answer. Basically it proposes to do this kind of thing:

```
childObject.parent = parentObject
childObject.matrix_parent_inverse = parentObject.matrix_world.inverted()
```

This works really great except for that it requires a call to `bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get().update()` first so that the parentObject's matrix_world matrix actually is correct. Although this approach is significantly faster than calling bpy.ops, it still requires a dependency graph update when it seems that all I really need is to update the parent's the matrix_world and nothing else.

Is there a way to only update the matrix_world without calling `bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get().update()` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found one solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57485640/4913592). As soon as any transformations are applied on the parent object (before the parenting happens I guess), then update the parent's matrices using this script:

```
def update_matrices(obj):
    if obj.parent is None:
        obj.matrix_world = obj.matrix_basis

    else:
        obj.matrix_world = obj.parent.matrix_world * \
                           obj.matrix_parent_inverse * \
                           obj.matrix_basis
```

This did the job for what I needed, but I'm not sure if there's a better way! If there is, feel free to post another answer!