# How to import multiple .obj files and keep the overall structure intact?

Tags: objects, import, obj

I am doing some research work on anatomy of human body, for which I want to use this project:  http://dbarchive.biosciencedbc.jp/en/bodyparts3d/download.html

This project is a 3D Model of human anatomy, containing hundreds of `.obj` files. Each `.obj` file is actually a model of a part of human body. **I want to import all the** `.obj` **files in such a way that the overall anatomy of the figure is intact**, i.e. all the structures are in their right place (so that I don't have to manually correct their position).

#### Edit:

Thanks @poor and @zeffii for your input. After a couple of hours of head-banging, everything seems to work now.
Here is what I did:

- Used the script given in the post mentioned by @poor.
- Modified the directory structure given in the script (which is for windows) to work with linux.
- Imported the `.obj` files using the script

[image: successful batch import]

The script now looks like this:

```
#Script to import multiple .obj files into blender
import os
import bpy

# put the location to the folder where the objs are located here in this fashion
path_to_obj_dir = '/home/user/Desktop/brainstem/'

# get list of all files in directory
file_list = sorted(os.listdir(path_to_obj_dir))

# get a list of files ending in 'obj'
obj_list = [item for item in file_list if item.endswith('.obj')]

# loop through the strings in obj_list and add the files to the scene
for item in obj_list:
    path_to_file = os.path.join(path_to_obj_dir, item)
    bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath = path_to_file)
```

#### Note:

There is something specific to this Human Anatomy project (link given above) that I want to share (hoping that it might help someone).

As mentioned by @zeffii, this project is huge. If yout try to import all the files at once, your system may crash.

The project contains some reference files, which have information about the file names and anatomical structures covered in them. This is very useful information because in this way you can divide the whole project into regions/systems and work with one region/system at a particular time.

The image given above is of **"Brain Stem"** which is made up of 11 `.obj` files.

[image: brainstem]

**Edit # 2:**

@poor has written an add-on for blender in order to import multiple .obj files simultaneously in a more user friendly way. I am now using this addon and it works flawlessly.

Here is the link: [How to batch import Wavefront OBJ files?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5064/batch-import-wavefront-obj/31825#31825)

**How to add this Addon:**

Step # 1:

First of all copy the code of the plugin and create a file named io_import_multiple_objs.py
[image: io_import_multiple_objs.py]

Step # 2:

In blender, goto "User Preferences" > "Addons" > "Install from file" and select the "io_import_multiple_objs.py" file you created in step # 1.

[image: install from file]

Step # 3:

Enable the addon

[image: Enable the addon]

Now you can batch-import multiple .obj files. :D
[image: batch import]

Thanks @poor for this great addon :D

Comment: just tried. works flawlessly if you give it the correct Path.

Comment: I have no experience with python. But based on common sense, I need to edit this line: "path_to_obj_dir = os.path.join('C:\\', 'objects')". What should be the syntax? I am on ubuntu linux and the files are on my desktop.

Comment: but.. it's a rather large folder, the import might take a while...or fail because it's too much geometry.

Comment: It works.. I have added all the details to the original question above. Thanks

Comment: @AhsanIqbal I've wrote a small addon: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31825/3710 to import multiple files. Hope this makes your life easier :)

Comment: @poor Thank you so much. The addon is really really great and works flawlessly... :D

Comment: Great! Glad I could help :) Maybe it is helpful for others to mention in your question that this addon is available, right? Could you edit your question?

Comment: Ofcourse. I should have thought about it earlier... :)