# How to translate imported obj's based on its respective filename?

Tags: python, scripting, objects, import

*Ok. So, I'm very new to Python, and I'm not very skilled with Blender either. I do have some C# experience, if it helps.*

I'm working on a module/add-on that takes OBJs made with World Machine and puts them in place in the Blender scene. I was trying to work with heightmaps, but seams never matched up. I've done some manual pulling around, and I know these can line up perfectly.

---

My problem is two fold:

**A)** The filename for each OBJ describes the location. They all have the naming format of "`object_x000_y000.obj`" Basically, where the numbers are, are how many units to the left or up I want to move the obj. But extracting this information from the file name makes NO Sense to me in python. I struggled with this in C#, but I can do it after some work. But python is like Greek to me right now. Any Documentation to help me chew up strings would be nice.

**B)** I'm struggling with understanding how to affect each individual object gets imported anyway. I want to rename and move each object. I wouldn't mind learning how to change the size for future reference also. I'm trying to avoid using an array, instead I want to work each import at a time per iteration in the loop. I would do this in C# by making a method I would loop, and return the "finished" object, but I don't get how to do this in Python.

Below is the entire script for reference, including comments that describe my problem:

```
import bpy
import os

from bpy.props import(StringProperty,
                     PointerProperty,
                     )

from bpy.types import(Panel,
                     Operator,
                     AddonPreferences,
                     PropertyGroup,
                     )

class MySettings(PropertyGroup):

    path = StringProperty(
    name="",
    description ="Path to Directory",
    default ="",
    maxlen=1024,
    subtype='DIR_PATH')


class WMImporterPanel(Panel):
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_WMImporter"
    bl_category = "WorldMachine Importer"
    bl_label = "WM Importer"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_context = 'objectmode'


    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column(align=True)
        scn = context.scene


        #Selecting Directory/Folder path
        col.label(text="Directory of Files")
        col.separator()
        dirpath = col.prop(scn.my_tool, "path", text="")


        #Button to perform import of meshes
        col.separator()
        col.operator("wmimport.importmeshes", text = "Import Meshes")

class OBJECT_OT_ImportButton(Operator):
    bl_idname = "wmimport.importmeshes"
    bl_label ="Import Meshes"

    def execute(self,context):
        scn = context.scene
        dirpath = scn.my_tool.path

        #print(dirpath)

        file_list = os.listdir(dirpath)

        obj_list = [item for item in file_list if item[-3:] == 'obj']
        #for file in obj_list:
        #    print (file)


        # Detect Naming Convention
        # Need Help
        # I want to pull the first file and rip the format from it.
        # Files come in the format of <filename>_x000_y000.obj
        # I want to use the filename to name each object imported, so if I called it Island
        # the object in blender will be called something like Island(X,Y)
        # where X = number following x in filename, and Y likewise.

        for item in obj_list:

            #Detect Location
            # Need Help
            #I want to get the X and Y value in the filename, so I can use that to
            #increment the object in corrosponding directions.


            fullpath = os.path.join(dirpath,item)
            bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=fullpath, axis_forward='Y', axis_up='Z')
            # Should I assign this obj to a variable?
            # newObj = bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=fullpath, axis_forward='Y', axis_up='Z')

        return{'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = PointerProperty(type=MySettings)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: For more pythonic questions (like your part 1) stackoverflow is a great resource.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175080/sscanf-in-python

Comment: The possibilities are endless. I'd go with a regex to find all digits in the filename in combination with a list comprehension in order to convert all strings into floats, this should be save enough in this case. [Here is an example](https://gist.github.com/p2or/e6431dec56227451cfd308707543939f) based on [this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5064/how-to-batch-import-wavefront-obj-files/31825#31825).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problem A, you can use splitting and slicing in Python:

```
def get_nameXY(item):
    name_set = item.split('_') #splits the string at every '_', returns a list
    x = name_set[1][1:] #gets the second value in the list starting at the second character
    y = name_set[2][1:-4] #gets the third value in the list starting at the second character and omitting the last four characters
    name = name_set[0] + '(' + x + ',' + y + ')' #combine the first value with x and y
    return name, float(x), float(y) #return the name with x and y as floats
```

Then you can call that function in you loop to name and position your imported object.(problem B)

```
for item in obj_list:

    #Detect Location
    name, x, y = get_nameXY(item)
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        obj.select = False #deselect all objects so imported object will be the only one selected

    fullpath = os.path.join(dirpath,item)
    bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=fullpath, axis_forward='Y', axis_up='Z')

    new_obj = bpy.context.selected_objects[0] # get object from list of selected
    new_obj.name = name #set the new name
    new_obj.location = (x,y,0)#set the location
```

I wasn't sure if your x,y was an actual position, but you can see how to get it and use it.

Comment: I was having some trouble with split before. I did some heavy research before you answered, so I kinda expected that to be the key. Thing is, for like 45 mins, I didn't know that there was 2 underscores before the xValue, so I was getting an empty... But I also really appreciate the example, cause I can see how it relates to how I would make a method in C#. I'm gonna hit the forms about 'def'

Comment: Just got it plugged into the script. I had to multiply X and Y by 2, but otherwise it WORKS PERFECTLY. Thank you so much for your help. You didn't just solve my problem, but helped me understand Python better