# Import multiple non OBJ models?

Tags: modeling, import

I'm having a problem trying to import multiple models from a format that uses a custom plugin. I press a to select them all, but only the first is imported. I have well over a thousand models, how would I go about doing this? I tried the solution here: [How to batch import Wavefront OBJ files?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5064/how-to-batch-import-wavefront-obj-files), but it only works for OBJs. How would I do this for .rip files?

The plugin I am using is located here:
https://github.com/Dummiesman/RipImport

Comment: I don't know enough about scripting, but my blind guess is you would replace `bpy.ops.import_scene.obj` with watever operator i used for importing rip files, possibly `bpy.ops.import_scene.rip` (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by calling `bpy.ops.import_scene.rip()` as shown below:

```
import os
import bpy

path_to_rip_dir = os.path.join('C:\\', 'rips') #where C:\\rips\\ has the list of rip files

file_list = sorted(os.listdir(path_to_rip_dir))

rip_list = [item for item in file_list if item.endswith('.rip')]

for item in rip_list:
    path_to_file = os.path.join(path_to_rip_dir, item)
    bpy.ops.import_scene.rip(filepath = path_to_file)
```

You will need to install the addon first as mentioned in the readme file of the addon:

- **Blender 32 Bit**:
     On 32 bit Blender installations, extract the downloaded ZIP file to
     C:\Program Files (x86)\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addon
- **Blender 64 Bit**:
        On 64 bit Blender installations, extract the downloaded ZIP file to
        C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\scripts\addons
- After you extract the Add-on, it will NOT show up in your
  import/export list by default!
- After extracting the Add-on, start Blender. Once Blender is
  started, open up File->User Preferences, and navigate over to the
  Add-ons tab. Find the add-on or search "NinjaRipper", and enable it. 
  Click "Save User Preferences" on the bottom of the dialog, and close 
  the dialog.
- Now you will be able to use the Add-on.

Comment: What do the different keywords mean? I can't seem to get this to run...

Comment: @ZacPerry just remove the **keywords from the last line, try `import_rip.load(self, context)` instead

Comment: Still does not function, gives me 'NameError: name 'import_rip' is not defined'. Maybe you could try basing your script off the one in the addon? Its on the github page in the original post.

Comment: @ZacPerry did you install the add-on? it works fine with me

Comment: The original addon? Yes. The script you pasted in, no. I used it in the text editor. Maybe try using an actual model:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0JlgUd0NeDVdmtOTGhFRGtDUXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ZacPerry what happens when you press the space bar and type "ninja" anything comes up?

Comment: Yes. The import function shows up. Does using a real model wrok for you? Here is one to test if you have none. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0JlgUd0NeDVdmtOTGhFRGtDUXc/view?usp=sharing/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57318/discussion-between-zac-perry-and-tak).

Comment: @ZacPerry Answer updated, but looks like the add-on is not working because even if you tried importing it manually using the spacebar Import NinjaRipper it doesn't work and throws many errors.

Comment: I seem to be able to import the models fine manually. How odd. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ZacPerry have you tried the new script? I updated my answer

Comment: Welp, it hasn't thrown me any errors, and blender froze, so its safe to say that it is working, thanks!