# Flattening a segment of a 3D curve in to a 2D plane (Z = 0)

Tags: python, scripting

I've been trying to flatten a set of points, which form a curve in 3D, to a plane, preferably Z = 0.

Here is the screen shot my view:
[image]

There are 3 kinds of objects in here:

1. Set of meshes {O3M6.L1.000 - O3M6.L1.013}
2. Curve drawn (using BTrace -> Objects Connect) connecting the centers of each mesh iteratively. You can find the implementation from the question asked in [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136103/scripting-the-generation-of-a-curve-from-the-set-of-mesh-centers-drawn-using-btr).
3. The minimum bounding box drawn using the [Minimum Bounding Box add-on](https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-minimum-bounding-volume/635618).

What I want is to align these centers vertically. So, if there is any way I could form a 2D plane approximately (with least away from the centers) passing through the centers, please feel free to answer.

I came across this idea, which may 'sound' easy:

1. Considering the rotations (X, Y, Z) of the cube, in the Transform window, mentioned in the above image, we can rotate the Box parallel to the plane Z = 0.
2. Note that these rotations could be applied to the Set of mesh we have as a group. Thus, the set of these meshes would be somewhat approximately parallel to Z = 0.

I don't know how to apply rotation parameters of one object to another. Any help is deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you calculate the average z value of all spline points and assign it back to each point, will that be reasonable solution?

Comment: I don't think so. Rotation implies change in orientation of objects. Computing mean values will just change the vertical (Z-axis) position. Though after we perform rotation, we can compute average Z-value (say Z*), and then translate each object towards Z=0 plane with Z* displacement.