# 2.9x - How to import multiple obj files?

Tags: import, obj

I just want to import multiple obj files into blender:

[image]

The addon by poor from [Import multiple OBJ files for Blender 2.8x](https://blenderartists.org/t/import-multiple-obj-files-for-blender-2-8x/1164372) on blenderartists does not seem to work for 2.9 anymore. Any help?

Comment: The answer has been updated at the end of 2019: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31825/31447... Tested the updated version of the add-on from the linked q/a, **no issues**. What exactly is not working? What's the error?

Comment: @YoungGilgo Where exactly is the addon shown in question code sourced? (notice the author list) AFAICT does not match the code in, or linked to in post mentioned.

Comment: You are right @batFINGER, this modified version comes from a blenderartist thread I've just found...

Comment: Updated the original add-on for 2.8+ a while ago (see the link brockmann posted) and it should work fine. If you encounter any issues let me know @YoungGilamesh

Answer (score -4):

You actually don't need to use an add-on to import multiple .obj files. You can manually continuosly keep on importing them. If you have saved it in a folder and there are too many of them, you can press shift and select the last file you want to import. If there are any files in the middle you don't need, go to the file explorer and drag the all the unnecessary files to the bottom. Then press shift to the last file you want to import and press import. The files might be imported might be in the wrong order and you have to arrange them. Or, you could import them one-by-one. I know it is difficult if there are too many files, but is less CPU intensive while loading all the meshes. This should work without any problems.

Comment: but i have tried it in 2.92, it only imported the last one ...

Comment: Then you will have to import it one by one. This is may be harder for you but you wouldn't want to put pressure on your CPU by importing the file at the same time because this would cause issues nd crashes while rendering.

Comment: Or, you could try dragging with your mouse, that is the fastest and most accurate way of getting it in one go.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'll keep on working !

Comment: Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer @Aster17

Comment: @brockmann I have seen the link you have shared. I am still new but I still don't know what I have done wrong. Can you please tell me and guide me on what I have done wrong.

Comment: Basically the same as last time, you did not read the question (*"read the question carefully*). -> Your answer is just a pile of guesswork, based on assumptions and just *wrong*. You can not hold down shift so you need an add-on to import multiple obj files, see the answers of the duplicate: *"Unfortunately, this is not possible by default... In 2.49, you could hold Shift..."*. -> I recommend try what you suggest before writing up an answer and please only answer if you understand the issue and have a real solution to the problem.