# Import multiple obj files in separate collections

Tags: scripting, import, workflow, collections, obj

https://gist.github.com/p2or/af5bc4fae39b16f8d505

This tool work very fine but exist a tool that import also multiple objs in separate collections, each for every single file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the add-on for Blender 2.92+ from [How to batch import Wavefront OBJ files?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5064/how-to-batch-import-wavefront-obj-files/31825#31825) and replace its `execute` method (starting at line 160) by the following lines of code:

```
    def execute(self, context):
        # get the folder
        folder = (os.path.dirname(self.filepath))
        # get the collection
        main_coll = context.scene.collection

        # iterate through the selected files
        for i in self.files:
            # create collection based on filename
            coll = bpy.data.collections.new(i.name.rsplit(".", 1)[0])
            main_coll.children.link(coll)
            layer_coll = context.view_layer.layer_collection.children.get(coll.name)
            context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = layer_coll
            
            # generate full path to file
            path_to_file = os.path.join(folder, i.name)
            
            # call obj operator and assign ui values                  
            bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(
                                filepath = path_to_file,
                                axis_forward = self.axis_forward_setting,
                                axis_up = self.axis_up_setting, 
                                use_edges = self.edges_setting,
                                use_smooth_groups = self.smooth_groups_setting, 
                                use_split_objects = self.split_objects_setting,
                                use_split_groups = self.split_groups_setting,
                                use_groups_as_vgroups = self.groups_as_vgroups_setting,
                                use_image_search = self.image_search_setting,
                                split_mode = self.split_mode_setting,
                                global_clamp_size = self.clamp_size_setting) 
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Result *(one collection per file)*:

[image]

Comment: It work perfectly! Thank You very much!